# TextChanged and switch statement to judge the changed textbox and rebuild chart data and update (Index out of Range) VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, select, indexing, indexoutofrangeexception, textchanged

I am struggling with using the switch statement and textchanged to update a chart in a panel on my form so that when text is changed the chart will rebind with the new values so as to create a dynamic chart in a sense.

My code below keeps returning an index out of range on the `Case T8K.Name : Me.yvals(7) = Convert.ToInt32(T8K.Text)`. (See below)

It may also be important to point out that all text boxes and the chart are located inside a panel

Could anyone please assist with what i may have done wrong.

```
Public Class Dashboard
    Private xvals As New List(Of Integer)
    Private yvals As New List(Of Integer)

Private Sub Dashboard_Load(Sender As Dashboard, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'loads data into the 'TCClientDBDataSet.Client_DB' table.
        Me.Client_DBTableAdapter.Fill(Me.TCClientDBDataSet.Client_DB)

        'Chart Setup
        'Dim A5K1 As Integer = T5K1.Text
        'Dim A5K2 As Integer = T5K2.Text
        'Dim A5K3 As Integer = T5K3.Text
        'Dim average = (A5K1 + A5K2 + A5K3) / 3

        Me.xvals = New List(Of Integer) From {1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000, 10000}
        Me.yvals = New List(Of Integer) From {T1K.Text, T2K.Text, T3K.Text, T4K.Text, T5K1.Text, T6K.Text, T7K.Text, T8K.Text, T9K.Text, T10K.Text}

        Dim xmaxvals() As Integer = ({1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000, 10000})
        Dim ymaxvals() As String = {tst_MaxOutput.Text, tst_MaxOutput.Text, tst_MaxOutput.Text, tst_MaxOutput.Text, tst_MaxOutput.Text, tst_MaxOutput.Text, tst_MaxOutput.Text, tst_MaxOutput.Text, tst_MaxOutput.Text, tst_MaxOutput.Text}

        Testpoint_Chart.Series.Clear()
        Testpoint_Chart.Series.Add("Test Data")
        Testpoint_Chart.Series.Add("Max Torque")

        With Testpoint_Chart.ChartAreas(0)
            .AxisX.Title = "Pressure (Psi)"
            .AxisX.Minimum = 1000
            .AxisX.Maximum = 10000
            .AxisX.Interval = 1000

            .AxisY.Interval = 1000
            .AxisY.Title = "Test Points (ft.lb)"

            'If T10K.Text > Math.Ceiling(tst_MaxOutput.Text / 1000) * 1000 Then
            .AxisY.Maximum = Math.Ceiling(T10K.Text / 1000) * 1000
            'Else
            '.AxisY.Maximum = Math.Ceiling(tst_MaxOutput.Text / 1000) * 1000
            'End If
        End With

        'Test Points
        With Testpoint_Chart.Series("Test Data")
            .IsVisibleInLegend = True
            .ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line
            .IsValueShownAsLabel = True
            .Points.DataBindXY(Me.xvals, Me.yvals)
        End With

        'Max Torque
        With Testpoint_Chart.Series("Max Torque")
            .IsVisibleInLegend = True
            .ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line
            .IsValueShownAsLabel = False
            .Color = Color.Red
            .Points.DataBindXY(xmaxvals, ymaxvals)
        End With
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox_TextChanged(Sender As TextBox, e As EventArgs) Handles T1K.TextChanged, T2K.TextChanged, T3K.TextChanged, T4K.TextChanged, T5K1.TextChanged, T6K.TextChanged, T7K.TextChanged, T8K.TextChanged, T9K.TextChanged, T10K.TextChanged
        Select Case Sender.Name
            Case T1K.Name : Me.yvals(0) = Convert.ToInt32(T1K.Text)
            Case T2K.Name : Me.yvals(1) = Convert.ToInt32(T2K.Text)
            Case T3K.Name : Me.yvals(2) = Convert.ToInt32(T3K.Text)
            Case T4K.Name : Me.yvals(3) = Convert.ToInt32(T4K.Text)
            Case T5K1.Name : Me.yvals(4) = Convert.ToInt32(T5K1.Text)
            Case T6K.Name : Me.yvals(5) = Convert.ToInt32(T6K.Text)
            Case T7K.Name : Me.yvals(6) = Convert.ToInt32(T7K.Text)
            Case T8K.Name : Me.yvals(7) = Convert.ToInt32(T8K.Text)
            Case T9K.Name : Me.yvals(8) = Convert.ToInt32(T9K.Text)
            Case T10K.Name : Me.yvals(9) = Convert.ToInt32(T10K.Text)
        End Select

        Me.Testpoint_Chart.Series("Test Data").Points.DataBindXY(Me.xvals, Me.yvals)
        Me.Testpoint_Chart.Update()
    End Sub
```

Comment: You shouldn't even be asking this question.  That you are indicates that you haven't actually debugged your code and no question should ever be asked here without debugging first.  Set breakpoints, step through your code and actually look at what it does.  That's why VS has a debugger built in.  One thing to think about: why are you creating a list of `Integer` values from `TextBoxes` when the form is loading and the user can't possibly have entered anything into them? Also, why are you using generic `Lists` at all when arrays would be more appropriate?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is clear that no debugging has been done.

Comment: Sorry I am still a junior when it comes to this, perhaps I’m not debugging correctly, thank you for your suggestions, I’ll rework the code.

Comment: *"perhaps I’m not debugging correctly"*.  You mustn't be.  I would start by placing a breakpoint on the line that sets `yvals` in the `Load` event handler and stepping from there to see whether that does what is expected.  Assuming it does (which I doubt), I would then put a breakpoint at the top of the `TextChanged` event handler and see what `yvals` is when that gets hit. If it is different to what it was at the end of the `Load` event handler then you need to start looking for where it changed.

Comment: Thank you, duly noted and will do- greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you greatly @jmcilhinney It turned out to be a conversion issue from String which means my index was empty, so after reworking the code a bit and using NumericUpDown controls with an array i managed to get it working.